# "Enter Heroku credentials" keeps coming up

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I'm running Winfows 10 64-bit version. I've downloaded Heroku and registered for an account. I go to my Command Prompt and type in "heroku login." It displays the message "Enter Heroku credentials:, email:, and password:". I type in my email and password to my Heroku account and hit enter. No error messages come up or anything, just another line reading: "Enter Heroku credentials:, email:, and password:". Every time I try to retype in my email and password, it is the same result.
I then tried the command "heroku auth:token", and got the error message "Heroku not logged in".
I'm still new to Heroku, so if this is an easy fix please don't be too hard on me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This is entirely unrelated to programming, it seems you have problem accessing your account on Heroku.  Please take your question up with them.

Comment: Weird bug that even though I was entering the right password into the login, changing the password on heroku sight seemed to fix it.